How to read a confluence page using an OAuth 2.0 custom app
I am building a custom app that allows a user to connect to Atlassian via OAuth. The signup flow works. I have a token with the scope. However, when i using token to access any page in confluence, I get the following error:
response is: <Response [401]>
Error: 401
Error details: {“code”:401,“message”:“Unauthorized; scope does not match”}
The source code is:
    cloudId = getAtlassianCloudId(access_token, 'confluence')
    print ('cloudId is: ', cloudId)

    if cloudId:
        # Call Confluence API
        headers = {
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        api_url = f'https://api.atlassian.com/ex/confluence/{cloudId}/rest/api/v2/pages/{pageId}'
        print(api_url)

        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
        print('response is: ', response)

        if response.status_code != 200:                 
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
            print(f"Error details: {response.text}")
            return None


Any suggestions on what I should differently?
Thanks!
Tried atlassian python library, different scopes in the developer console

Figured out the issue. the URL for pages is 'wiki/api/v2/pages/' and not 'rest/api/v2/pages/'
